# MinIO STS: cannot get temporary credentials

Tags: docker, wso2, minio

I'm following along [this](https://github.com/aarushiarya/minio-idp) guide on how to get temporary credentials from minIO given an access token than I'm currently getting from WSO2.

However, upon reaching step 3 (the actual step that gets the temp credentials from minIO using STS API), I'm getting this error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>XMinioUnknownAPIRequest</Code>
    <Message>Unknown API request at /minio/sts</Message>
    <Resource>/minio/sts</Resource>
    <RequestId></RequestId>
    <HostId>9d60f8b3-f2f3-48f0-94bf-2f416d226a86</HostId>
</Error>
```

( tested with postman and with `curl -X POST -k "{token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:9000/minio/sts`, same error on both )

I'm running minIO on docker (minio/minio), `MINIO_IDENTITY_OPENID_CONFIG_URL` is correctly set and I set `MINIO_IDENTITY_OPENID_CLIENT_ID` to a random string.

I's there something I'm missing? Do I have to enable STS on minio somehow?
thanks